# How do I make another block of text?

Tags: android

I understand how to display some text with the user input, but what I'm confused about is how to add a completely new block of text under the one I have right now (I want to put a new block of text because I want the size of the text to be different). Right now, I display "Welcome [user input]!"

In my activity file I have:

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = "                Welcome " + intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE) + "!";

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(25);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
    }
```

And in my fragment.xml file, I have:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEST"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

With some help from the feedback I got from other users, I added android:text="TEST" too the second "TextView". And I also added the android:orientation="vertical" to LinearLayout. But the "TEST" still doesn't show up when I run the app! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `android:orientation="vertical"` on your `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Any ideas on how to add another block of text?

Comment: That should do it. You could add `android:text="TEST"` to both `TextView`s to see the effect.

Comment: Hmm, so even after putting that, only the "Welcome [user input]!" line shows up. :(

Comment: Let me update my code so that you can see what I did.

Comment: what the MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE? Did you set this value from starting activity?

Comment: Add code when you start this activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not associating your layout to your `Activity`. Instead, you are adding a `TextView` on runtime, that is created on runtime. That's why only one `TextView` appears. You have to use `setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);` instead of `setContentView(textView);`, so your `Activity` fetches your layout.

Edit: In your layout, add ids to your `TextViews`, so you can access them from your `Activity` code, like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myFirstTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="TEST1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mySecondTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="TEST2" />
```

Then on your `Activity`, inside `onCreate()`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = "                Welcome " + intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE) + "!";

        TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myFirstTextView);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mySecondTextView);

        textView1.setTextSize(25);
        textView1.setText(message);

    }
```

Comment: Do I need to change anything for the first block of text? Because now, it's only displaying "TEST". Thanks!

Comment: @Karen Yes, you need to apply an id to your first layout TextView. And then summon it form inside your Activity. I'll update my answer. Don't forget to upvote it :D

Comment: Just wondering, since I'm using user input in the first block of text, how would that look if I put it in android:text??

Comment: Do not put in in android:text, because those values are never going to change, unless you change them on your code. Just use `setText()` on your code to change it dynamically,

Comment: Ah ok, so how would it look if I used setText()?? Sorry, first time making an Android app. :(

Comment: If you keep your 3 lines below "//Create text View" comment, you will get three `TextViews`, 2 of them from the layout, and one created Dynamically. So, I advise you to remove the `TextView` created dynamically (not from the layout), if you only want to have two `TextViews`.

Comment: Ok, so for displaying the text with the user input, how would the code look?? Would I still need an id for the first TextView/the TextView textView1 = ...? And would that mean that I need two remove the 3 lines below "//Create text View"??

Comment: I think I'm still a little confused about the code for the activity file. :(

Comment: Yes, just keep your TextViews from your layout. Remove the one below your //Create text View comment. Then use textView1.setText(message) to set your user input text on your first TextView.

Comment: Oh ok! Do you think you could include this stuff in your code that you put above?? It'd be a big help to see it done the right way!

Comment: Yes, so you can still have two TextViews. Just stick with your TextViews from the layout. :D

Comment: Thank you SO much for your patience and help! :D

Answer (score 1):

Assuming fragment.xml is in the res/layout folder

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment);
```

instead of

```
setContentView(textView);
```